# When creating a windows form app I get the following error could not find dll under refint

Tags: .net, winforms

I have tried changing the framework but that doesn't solve my problem.

Seems to randomly occur.

Error Code below:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'obj\Debug\net6.0-windows7.0\refint\FirstApp.dll'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.CopyRefAssembly.Copy()
FirstApp    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   4651

Comment: Do you have more than one project in your solution? There's not a whole lot to go on here but it's the kind of thing that can happen when `Project\Project Dependencies...` isn't set up correctly in a multi-project sln. When it's not, success or failure depends on whether or not that dll is present from a previous build the so the error _can_ come and go depending on whether you're running a `build` or a `rebuild`.

Comment: I only have 1 project.

Comment: doesn't seem to work..

Comment: didn't seem to work because of antivirus.